# Possible to add second predictor that positively correlates with y but kills the effect of another predictor?

Tags: r, regression, simulation

I simulated data that includes two x-variables, both positively correlated with y. How should I simply edit 'x2' so that it positively correlates with 'y' but removes the association between 'x1' and 'y'?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jtools)

set.seed(123)

n = 50
d = tibble(y = rnorm(n, 50, 10))

d = d %>% 
  arrange(y) %>% 
  mutate(x1 = y + rnorm(nrow(d), 0, 3),
         x2 = y + rnorm(nrow(d), 0, 10))

m1 = lm(y ~ x1, data = d)
effect_plot(m1, "x1", interval = T)
```

[image]

```
m2 = lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = d)
effect_plot(m2, "x1", interval = T)
```

[image]

Comment: In your example, x1 is much closer correlated with x2 based on the standard deviations of your added noise.  `x2 = y + rnorm(nrow(d), 0, 1)` would instead attribute a larger effect to x2 compared to x1, if that's what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could make x2 so that it correlates closely to x1:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(jtools)

set.seed(123)

n = 50
d = tibble(y = rnorm(n, 50, 10))

d = d %>% 
  arrange(y) %>% 
  mutate(x1 = y + rnorm(nrow(d), 0, 3),
         x2 = x1 + rnorm(nrow(d), 0, 0.5))
```

This way `x1` alone has a positive effect:

```
m1 = lm(y ~ x1, data = d)
effect_plot(m1, "x1", interval = T)
```

[image]

and `x2` alone has a positive effect

```r
m2 = lm(y ~ x2, data = d)
effect_plot(m2, "x2", interval = T)
```

[image]

But the effect of x1 when combined with x2 is effectively "killed"

```r
m3 = lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = d)
effect_plot(m3, "x1", interval = T)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! But why decreasing the SD of X2 did this?

Comment: @st4co4 if x1 and x2 are completely correlated (say for example x1 == x2), then x1 adds nothing at all to the model once x2 is taken into account.